# Not possible to give column names to concatenated Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

From a pandas dataframe I calculate mean(), sd() and max() from all variables with pandas built in functions. I get back three pandas serieses.

```
import pandas as pd

df_FALKO_R_scores_mean = df_FALKO_R_scores_only.mean()

df_FALKO_R_scores_sd = df_FALKO_R_scores_only.std()

df_FALKO_R_scores_max = df_FALKO_R_scores_only.max()
```

Than I concatenate the three serieses to get an output of mean, sd and max for every variable.

The Problem is, as you can see below, although I add "names" to the concat() function, the labels of the variables are named 0, 1 and 2. This is not readable, especially if I want to plot those numbers. How can I manage to get a Pandas series with the column labels ['mean','sd','max']? I also tried "ignore_index" True and False.

```
df_FALKO_R_scores_mean_sd_max = pd.concat([df_FALKO_R_scores_mean, df_FALKO_R_scores_sd, df_FALKO_R_scores_max], names=['mean', 'sd', 'max'], axis=1, ignore_index=True)

print(df_FALKO_R_scores_mean_sd_max)
```

Output:

```
                     0         1    2
R_fd_s_01a_s  1.026490  0.631897  2.0
R_fd_e_01b_s  0.794702  0.802645  2.0
R_fd_e_01c_s  1.039735  1.124757  4.0
R_fd_p_02a_s  1.390728  0.848320  3.0
R_fd_p_02b_s  0.880795  0.552897  2.0
R_fd_p_03_s   1.132450  1.004493  3.0
R_fd_s_04_s   0.834437  0.769679  2.0
R_fd_e_05_s   0.403974  0.694539  2.0
R_fd_p_06a_s  1.105960  0.644488  2.0
R_fd_e_06b_s  1.337748  0.979030  3.0
R_fd_e_07_s   1.192053  1.320178  4.0
R_fd_e_08a_s  0.748344  0.741337  2.0
R_fd_e_08b_s  0.529801  0.737635  2.0
R_fd_p_09a_s  1.688742  1.312430  4.0
R_fd_p_09b_s  0.701987  0.839005  3.0
R_fw_01_s     0.774834  0.731867  2.0
R_fw_02_s     0.761589  0.797568  2.0
R_fw_03_s     0.841060  0.857070  2.0
R_fw_04_s     0.589404  0.675983  2.0
R_fw_05_s     0.403974  0.655020  2.0
R_fw_06_s     0.211921  0.441351  2.0
R_fw_07_s     0.536424  0.789724  2.0
R_fw_08_s     0.927152  0.566855  2.0
R_fw_09a_s    1.317881  0.843571  2.0
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `agg()` instead of creating three different calculations and concatenating the results?

```
df_FALKO_R_scores_only.agg(['mean', 'std', 'max'], axis=1)
```

It will give you results with proper column names.

You didn't add any input, but I believe it could work in this case.

**EDIT:**

If you want to use `pd.concat`, you can name each series, example:

```
df_FALKO_R_scores_mean.name = 'mean'
```

Or you can just name output columns by using a list.

```
df_FALKO_R_scores_mean_sd_max.columns = ['mean', 'std', 'max']
```

Comment: The Problem with this approach is twofold (Btw. I wanted mean etc. over every variable (or item) not over every indiviual, so it has to be applied on axis=0).

Comment: I edited my answer, maybe some of these will be helpful. If not, you could edit your question and provide some sample dataframe.

Comment: Yes! To directly name the columns via pd.columns did the trick. Thanks a lot!